# Passing parameters through the route laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, foreign-keys, parameter-passing

I am trying to pass an id with the route when i submit a form.
when i pass a hard coded id like

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('submit.lmo_list', ['id'=>7]) }}">
```

it works. the table shows the foreign key id as 7.

when i pass the id from the user table

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('submit.lmo_list', ['id'=>auth()->user->id]) }}">
```

this also works and the id field in the database shows the user id.

I want to pass an id from the notification table and when i try to do something like

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('submit.lmo_list', ['id'=>notification()->id]) }}">
```

it throws an error saying method notification not found.

notification controller

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    $notification = Notification::create([
        'unit_code'=>$request->unit_code,
        'unit_name'=>$request->unit_name,
        'project_title'=>$request->project_title,
        'project_ref_number'=>$request->project_ref_number,
        'storage_location'=>$request->storage_location,
        'keeper_name'=>$request->keeper_name,
        'user_id'=>Auth::user()->id
        ]);

        return redirect()-> route('show.lmo_form', $notification->id);

}
```

here i am passing the notification id with the url after the form is submitted and it correctly shows the id in the url.

notification lmo controller

```
 public function create(Request $request, $notification_id)
{


    /*this loop is because im adding rows dynamically to the table*/
    $count = count($request->input('lmo_name'));

        for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){

        $data = AddLmoNotification::create([
        'lmo_name'=>$request->lmo_name[$i],
        'lmo_risk_level'=>$request->lmo_risk_level[$i],
        'lmo_quantity'=>$request->lmo_quantity[$i],
        'lmo_volume'=>$request->lmo_volume[$i],
        'notification_id'=>$notification_id
        ]);
    }

        return redirect()->route('show.go_to_notification');
}
```

This is the controller which inserts data into the second table along with the id of the first table.

When i submit the form i get an error

> undefined method notification()

Please Help

Let me know if you require to see any other files such as the models and the database migrations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of a notification() helper. Are you sure you intend to make this call

```
... route('submit.lmo_list', ['id' => notification()->id]) ...
```

and not

```
... route('submit.lmo_list', ['id' => $notification->id]) ...
```

where you pass a variable to the route function?
Because that might just be the function not found.
If this does not solve your issue, a list of variables you pass into your view might be helpful to understand whats going on. (Please provide the controller method returning the view), also the complete error message + stack generated by laravel could be of much help.

I'd recommend you pass the notification to your view like this

```
return view('Notification.notification_for_lmo')
    ->with('notification', $notification);
```

you can now access your notification via `$notification` inside your view and apply the route method as suggested above.

[This](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#displaying-data) might help you out when trying to pass data to your views.

Comment: when i do   
         `... route('submit.lmo_list', ['id' => $notification->id])`
it says undefined variable: notification

i have a notification table and a notification_type_a table. the notification table hasMany notification_type_a. So i am trying to pass the notification id to the notification_type_a table as foreign key.

Comment: I am pretty sure the initial 'undefined method notification()' is due to the absence of said method in your view. Did you pass the notification into your view?

Comment: i am not really sure if i did. i just started laravel, sorry for being that dumb. can you please elaborate. thank you

Comment: return view('Notification.notification_for_lmo', compact($notification));

i pass the notification onto the view in this way.

Comment: Glad I could help